# How to bind css to an element using Knockout JS and Bootstrap based on query string value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a menu sub menu style

```
<ul>
 <li> <a href="http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu1"> Menu 1 </a></li>
 <li> <a href="http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu2"  data-bind="class: active"> Menu 2 </a></li>
 <li> <a href="http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu3"> Menu 3 </a>
  <ul>
   <li> <a href="http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu3_1"> Sub Menu 3.1 </a></li>
   <li> <a href="http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu3_2"> Sub Menu 3.2 </a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Now on click of any menu I am navigating to respective page with appropriate query string values like `http:\\questionbox.in?action=menu2`

So based on query string parameter"action=menu2",I want to set active class to the the respective href i.e bind the css class active to menu 2 using Knockout.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? I don't understand what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: navigating to respective page is `async` ? (since there is no url on those `a` tags)

Comment: You need to explain more to get your desired help. There are some facts which are vague. Like if you set a class to css binding do you want to remove a current active CSS from other menus or submenus? (only active menus gets that CSS?). Are you generating that list using `knockout` `foreach` ?  what is the structure of your Model?

Comment: I have modified the description of my question. Hope that is understanding.

Comment: you have to build a view model first describing your menu and
when you are done , add bindings to your html

Comment: There is no "class" binding. Have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html